# caption left justified with the picture

Tags: floats, captions

i would like to do following, if i have a float and want to put in a picture, which is not as wide as the column. Then i want the caption to be left justified with the picture, like in following:
[image]

but the caption gets left justified with the column if i use

```
\captionsetup{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=off}
```

with the caption package.

is it possible to get what i want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution relies on `floatrow`: the cation is justified between the natural width of the image.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\captionsetup{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=off}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[! htbp]
 \centering
 \begin{floatrow}
 \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{ \caption{Lewis Carroll}}{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{Charles-Dodgson}}
 \end{floatrow}
\end{figure}


There was a table set out under a tree in front of the house, and the
March Hare and the Hatter were having tea at it: a Dormouse was sitting
between them, fast asleep, and the other two were using it as a
cushion, resting their elbows on it, and talking over its head. ‘Very
uncomfortable for the Dormouse,’ thought Alice; ‘only, as it’s asleep, I
suppose it doesn’t mind.’

The table was a large one, but the three were all crowded together at
one corner of it: ‘No room! No room!’ they cried out when they saw Alice
coming. ‘There’s PLENTY of room!’ said Alice indignantly, and she sat
down in a large arm-chair at one end of the table.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You could wrap image and caption in a minipage:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=off}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
%
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{.7\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
            \caption{test}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Alternative solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=off}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\newlength{\imagewidth}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
%
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \setlength{\imagewidth}{.7\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{example-image}
    \captionsetup{width=\imagewidth}
    \caption{test}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 But you are playing with the fire: if the OP accepts your nice answer, you will miss 66,666. ;-)

Comment: @marmot Very true - I hope the OP understands the importance of palindromes :)

Comment: yeah i had that idea already, but is it possible to make the width of the minipage automatic? and what is the problem with palindromes?

Comment: @A.Ston The problem with palindromes is that if this would have answered your question and if you had accepted my answer, I would have gained 15 rep points and missed the palindrome :) For the automatic solution: I think I know an older answer - let me quickly search for it

Comment: yeah with automatic i mean like based on the content, then i could redefine the environment with renewcommand or idk, cuz kinda lazy to put the minipage every time :D . so you dont want me to accept?

Comment: Oups, hope you don't mind that I pushed you over the 66,666. Congratulations, by the way ;-)

Comment: @A.Ston I added another solution using `\captionsetup{width=...}`.

Comment: @moewe Thanks for your congratulations! I already made a screenshot of my profile page in time :)